# I'm done with my Git repository, and I have it cloned to my computer. Do I delete it, or how do I basically be done with it?

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm fully done with one of my git repositories. I don't want anything to do with it anymore. I cloned it to my computer when i created it, but now what do i do? Do i just delete the folder, or is there some sort of command i run in the terminal that tells it i'm done?

I'm on mac if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you do not need anything in that folder, you can just delete the folder.